# Maven: how to mitigate mvn "fileNameMapping has been removed ... use outputFileMapping instead"

Tags: java, maven, websphere, open-liberty

using mvn install I get the error message "fileNameMapping has been removed with version 3.0.0 but you are still using it...".

First of all, I am not using "fileNameMapping" anywhere, but I might use some pom which in turn might use it.

First question: How do I find the pom which does this?  And second question: When does that kick in anyway? Documentation (https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-ear-plugin-2.6/examples/customize-file-name-mapping.html) says that my project has the same artifactId for different groups.  How can this be? The artifact id is unique, or what does the word "group" mean in this case?

Comment: Hi, Maven modules have "coordinates" specifying group, artifact, version.   So if you have an EAR that's going to contain modules of type (WAR, EJB JAR, etc.) a natural way to construct the module names within the EAR is to combine these Maven coordinates to "flatten" the module filename within the EAR.    (Similar for WAR).  That's what you'll see if you look at the default value:  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html#outputFileNameMapping, and there's also some doc for more advanced cases:  https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-mapping/index.html

Comment: Hopefully that helps as a starting point to get your bearings, but if you have a more detailed question you should include more details of your POMs (since you seem to be using the EAR plugin you likely have a multi-module project so you might need to share details of multiple modules), and also explain what you are trying to do, and then perhaps what problems you're having or what output you're not understanding.

Comment: Please show the full pom file...also the whole error output ...